# How to Convert ProcessInfo to WTS_PROCESS_INFO

Tags: c#, c++, process, pinvoke, marshalling

I am trying to invoke `WTSEnumerateProcesses()` but am having some trouble converting type `ProcessInfo` to `WTS_PROCESS_INFO`.

This is the code I have so far:

**ProcessInfo**

```
    class ProcessInfo
    {
        public int basePriority;
        public int handleCount;
        public int mainModuleId;
        public long pageFileBytes;
        public long pageFileBytesPeak;
        public long poolNonpagedBytes;
        public long poolPagedBytes;
        public long privateBytes;
        public int processId;
        public string processName;
        public int sessionId;
        public ArrayList threadInfoList;
        public long virtualBytes;
        public long virtualBytesPeak;
        public long workingSet;
        public long workingSetPeak;

        public ProcessInfo()
        {

        }
    }
```

**WTS_PROCESS_INFO**

```
    public struct WTS_PROCESS_INFO
    {
        public int SessionID;
        public int ProcessID;
        // This is spointer to a string...
        public IntPtr ProcessName;
        public IntPtr userSid;
    }
```

**WTSEnumerateProcesses()**

```
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WTSEnumerateProcesses(
        IntPtr serverHandle, // Handle to a terminal server. 
        Int32 reserved,     // must be 0
        Int32 version,      // must be 1
        ref IntPtr ppProcessInfo, // pointer to array of WTS_PROCESS_INFO
        ref Int32 pCount     // pointer to number of processes
    );

    public static WTS_PROCESS_INFO[] WTSEnumerateProcesses()
    {
        IntPtr pProcessInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
        int processCount = 0;
        var hServer = OpenServer("XA7-06");

        if (!WTSEnumerateProcesses(hServer, 0, 1, ref pProcessInfo, ref processCount))
            return null;

        IntPtr pMemory = pProcessInfo;
        WTS_PROCESS_INFO[] processInfos = new WTS_PROCESS_INFO[processCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < processCount; i++)
        {
            processInfos[i] = (ProcessInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pProcessInfo, typeof(WTS_PROCESS_INFO));
            pProcessInfo = (IntPtr)((int)pProcessInfo + Marshal.SizeOf(processInfos[i]));
        }

        WTSFreeMemory(pMemory);
        return processInfos;
    }
```

My issue is near the end of the `WTSEnumerateProcesses()` method on this line:

```
processInfos[i] = (ProcessInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pProcessInfo, typeof(WTS_PROCESS_INFO));
```

Where I think I may have missed out a step in defining the relationship between `WTS_PROCESS_INFO` and `ProcessInfo`, but I am not sure how to do this. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

This is the error I am seeing:

```
// Cannot implicitly convert type 'ProcessInfo' to 'WTS_PROCESS_INFO'
```

Comment: You need to define the structure WTS_PROCESS_INFO in the c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ProcessInfo` type is unrelated to `WTS_PROCESS_INFO`. So this line:

```
processInfos[i] = (ProcessInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pProcessInfo, 
    typeof(WTS_PROCESS_INFO));
```

actually contains two errors. The compiler picks up one. Specifically that `processInfos[i]` is of type `WTS_PROCESS_INFO` and is not assignment compatible with `ProcessInfo`. The other mistake is a little more subtle. Your cast of the value returned by `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` to the type `ProcessInfo` is wrong. The value returned by `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` is a boxed `WTS_PROCESS_INFO`. So that line of code should be:

```
processInfos[i] = (WTS_PROCESS_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pProcessInfo, 
    typeof(WTS_PROCESS_INFO));
```

Your pointer arithmetic can fail in a 64 bit process. If you are using a recent version of .net you can perform arithmetic directly on IntPtr:

```
pProcessInfo += Marshal.SizeOf(processInfos[i]);
```

Or if you target older .net versions you should perform the arithmetic in a 64 bit context by casting to `ulong` rather than `int`.

As for your `ProcessInfo` type, I think that's just a mis-think on your part. There appears to be no use for that type here.

If I were you I would force the use of the Unicode version of `WTSEnumerateProcessesW`, for instance like this:

```
[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "WTSEnumerateProcessesW", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool WTSEnumerateProcesses(
    ....
);
```

To read the process name as a string, pass the pointer returned in the `WTS_PROCESS_INFO` struct to `Marshal.PtrToStringUni`.

Comment: Thanks David your first suggestsion seems to have solved my issue so that I end up with a filled-in WTS_PROCESS_INFO[] ! However, these items all have a `ProcessName` property which appears to be made up of a collection of numbers - is there any way of converting this to a string name (for example explorer.exe) or is this not that kind of process name?

Comment: Wow thanks so much David Hefferman - extremely helpful. When I convert my name using `string name = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(processInfos[I].processName)` I end up with "睤\u2e6d硥e瑣杸 (but waaay longer) - I'm guessing this is part of why you recommend using the Unicode version

Comment: Yes indeed. What has happened there is that you have converted an ANSI encoded byte array as though it was UTF-16.

Comment: And indeed adding `EntryPoint = "WTSEnumerateProcessesW"` to the Dllimport resolved this last issue. many th anks - I am very grateful as this will help me read and understand more about Marshalling and Dllimports!!

Comment: FWIW, I think that process with the mangled encoding is actually named `dwm.exe`.